Example of a Boolean Ring with infinite injective dimension over itself
It is known that Boolean rings can have infinite global dimension (free Boolean algebra on a large enough number of generators) [ see The Global Dimension of Boolean Rings by Pierce]. Are there any with infinite injective dimension over itself?
If so, is there a criterion for when a Boolean ring has infinite injective dimension over itself? (is it possible to describe this condition in terms of the profinite sets corresponding to the ring?)

Did you want an example or a criterion? The header says one, the text says the other.

I would like an example. And if possible I also want to understand all examples (but just having one would be nice too)

Not my subject, so I hope I haven't misunderstood, but I don't think there are any examples. I have read that Boolean algebras, regarded as Boolean rings, are von Neumann regular, so they are Ding-Chen rings, i.e., two-sided coherent rings of finite self-FP-injective dimension on both sides. FP-injective dimension is an upper bound for injective dimension, so Boolean rings have finite injective dimension over themselves on each side. See pgs. 20-21 of this Wang--Estrada paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.03010

sorry I'm a little confused. There are more fp-injectives than injectives right? why is fp-injective dimension an upper bound for injective dimension?

Aha, you're right: I had it backwards, thinking of "finitely presented injectives" rather than "FP-injectives"! Indeed the FP-injective dimension is a LOWER bound for injective dimension. So what I wrote does not exclude the possibility that a Boolean ring might still be Ding-Chen without being Gorenstein--or more accurately (since Noetherianness is assumed with the Gorenstein condition), without being of finite injective dimension over itself, precisely the situation you are asking about.

Although reading one of the references of that paper you linked: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.1615 Corollary 6.13 seems to imply that for a Boolean ring R, D(R) = K(Inj R) not sure if that's relevant. (btw R is never Noetherian unless it is like finite dimensional I think)
